# Why I get different root CA from Browsers

Tags: c, ssl, openssl

Currently, I am using `openssl` library to parse a `https` web site certificate information.

I use `SSL_get_peer_cert_chain()` to get web site https certificate chain. after I enumerate it, I can get web site related CA certificate information. but when I compare result I find the root CA in result is different from browsers show.

(ex, about www.google.com, I want to get **GeoTrust Global CA** certificate information.)

**SSL_get_peer_cert_chain() API result**:

```
Certificate - GeoTrust Global CA  

Issuer Full Name    OU = Equifax Secure Certificate Authority,O = Equifax,C = US  
Subject CN = GeoTrust Global CA,O = GeoTrust Inc.,C = US  

Fingerprint (SHA-1) 73:59:75:5C:6D:F9:A0:AB:C3:06:0B:CE:36:95:64:C8:EC:45:42:A3  
Fingerprint (MD5)   2E:7D:B2:A3:1D:0E:3D:A4:B2:5F:49:B9:54:2A:2E:1A
```

**Chrome Browser shows**:

```
Certificate - GeoTrust Global CA  

Issuer Full Name    CN = GeoTrust Global CA,O = GeoTrust Inc.C,= US    
Subject CN = GeoTrust Global CA,O = GeoTrust Inc.C,= US
```

From above result, `SSL_get_peer_cert_chain()` API do not return root CA certificate, instead, it return a certificate issued by `Equifax Secure Certificate Authority`, I think `GeoTrust Global CA` should be the correct ROOT CA, and I think it is installed on local computer.

**Question**: How Can I get this root CA shown by Chrome?

Thanks!